# Is it possible to use a control without putting it on a form in VB6?

Tags: forms, vb6, controls

I'm pretty sure about the answer to this, but I'm trying a variety of things to get a very stubborn project to work.  One idea was to try to run code through a control without defining it on a form.

So, for example, my original code looked like this:

```
frmProcess.MyViewer.MaxPageSize = 100
frmProcess.MyViewer.ResetPages
frmProcess.MyViewer.AddPageToView "C:\TestPage1.txt"
```

I've changed it to:

```
Dim objViewer As MyViewer
objViewer.MaxPageSize = 100
objViewer.ResetPages
objViewer.AddPageToView "C:\TestPage1.txt"
```

I get an error window with "Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set".

But there doesn't seem to be a way to 'set' this control. Is this just impossible, or is there another way to do it that doesn't require a form?

EDIT: I ended up abandoning this entire path of activity, as an alternate solution was found that got around the problem I was having with this form freezing. I don't want to delete this question in case someone else comes along and can benefit from the answers, which are potentially useful.

Comment: The code shown is equivalent to `Dim objViewer As MyViewer = Nothing`. There was no control created.

Comment: Try Set objViewer = New MyViewer if you have it referenced in your project, else try using CreateObject.

Comment: Define `defining it on a form`. Because if you mean creating it, then no. How can you run code on something that doesn't exist? Does not compute. You must create an object, whether through IDE or through code like jac suggested.

Comment: @jac Yes, I should have specified that's what I meant by saying I couldn't set the control. If I use `new`, I get the compile-time error  "invalid use of new keyword". I have a reference to the ActiveX dll for the control, so I'm not sure what else would need to be done to make that work, unless it's an issue with referencing the oca vs the dll, which I'm not super clear on. With CreateObject, I get "Run-time error '429': ActiveX component can't create object" at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

Try this on a form.

```
Dim objViewer As MyViewer

Set objViewer = Controls.Add("MyViewer", "MyViewer1")
objViewer.MaxPageSize = 100
objViewer.ResetPages
objViewer.AddPageToView "C:\TestPage1.txt"
```

Comment: I was really trying to do this without a form at all. Trying this code gave me two results: either it complained that the control already existed (since I had placed a control with that name on the form) or it said it couldn't add it with a new name.

Answer (score 1):

I've had similar situations in the past. If all else fails and you have to use a form you can do something crude like

1) Set the .Left property of the control to a negative number (like -10000) so the control doesn't appear on the form, the user can not see it

2) Make the entire form not visible..

Comment: I probably should have given more backstory on this. This application originally had the form as invisible.  The problem is that the control is freezing up, and I'm flailing around trying to figure out a way to run it without having that happen.  But your suggestions would work if just hiding it were all I wanted to do.

Answer (score 0):

ActiveX controls normally expect a number of services from their containers, for example persistence.  They are also "packaged and marked" in ways that set the kinds of instantiation they support.

See [Introduction to ActiveX Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa751972(v=vs.85).aspx).

While it is perfectly possible for a control to be created in such a way as to make many of the available services optional, most controls are created from template code that requires a number of them.  And most controls that are "visible at runtime" are going to require container services.

However that doesn't mean a control can't be designed to support containerless instantiation.  A well known example of such a control is Microsoft Script Control 1.0 (MSScriptControl.ScriptControl) which can be used either way.